# How Virtual Machine or Compiler diagnoses two objects with the same name of variable in Java?

Tags: java, object, variables, reference

I have a problem to understand how Virtual Machine or compiler works! 
Consider two JButton have created in the following way:

```
    JButton jb =new JButton("firstJB");
    jb.addActionListener(this);
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(jb);
    jb = new JButton("secondJB");
    jb.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(jb);
```

The problem is how VM or compiler diagnoses this two objects.

They have the same name for variable, and variable supposed to reference to the address in memory. We have a variable for two addresses?

I thought maybe compiler diagnoses them by their ActionEvent, but how? Can you help me to figure out how machine work with them?

Comment: The contentPane makes a **copy** of the reference that you pass in.  So when you assign `jb` a second time, the first reference is not lost.

Comment: you don't have two variables linked to jb. you merely overwrite the one by the other, replacing the original reference  by the new one

Comment: Java passes _references_ **by value**!

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `new JButton("firstJB")` to the `jb` variable, the variable holds a reference to the first `JButton` object.

Later, when you assign `new JButton("secondJB")` to the `jb` variable, it holds a reference to the second `JButton` object. That second assignment doesn't affect the first `JButton` object, which was already added to the `Container` object (the `contentPane.add(jb)` call stores a reference to the `JButton` object within the `Container` object), and therefore won't be garbage collected.

Comment: Thank you Eran, but what does refere to first JButton? How compiler diognose them?

Comment: The compiler doesn't think about the variable name. He has two different places in memory for the two buttons. If you think of how the program is able to distinguish between the two buttons with the ActionListener, then you have to know that class listening to the ActionEvent is able two compare the references or even the name of the button, which is the default ActionCommand of the ActionEvent.

Comment: @Tayebeh The `Container` object has a `List<Component>` instance variable, and each time you call `contentPane.add(jb)`, the reference held by the `jb` variable is added to that `List`. At the end of your snippet, references to both `JButton` objects are held by that `List`.

Comment: Thanks you all. you really helped me.